# New Marriage with children

Tags: nikah

Salamin alaykum..
I am a father of 2 boys 5 and 8 years old. I am divorced. And my ex wife live in another country. So I am alone with children.

I have found a woman I would like to do nikah with.. She is also divorced with 1 boy but also has a girl that is 11 years old..

I would like to ask if it is permissible for us to do nikah, thinking that she has a girl?

If possible I would reguest the answer in English and Arabic to show family elders.. 
We are Muslim following hanafi

May God bless you

Maassalame.

Comment: Instead of deleting the content of your post you could delete the post (you should have a delete link). We are a Q&A site as we found a Question which seems identic to yours we identified yours as a duplicate and you can check the link of the former question, if anything there seems unclear or different to your request you may edit your posted question and make clear what these differences are then your question would be reviewed and hopefully answered as you wish. Finally I recommend you to take our [tour] and check ou [help] to learn how this site works.